# Using Parse path to remove extension in model builder. ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, python-parser, error-000354

I am trying to iterate through a folder of rasters (approx 6,000) and calculate zonal statistics for roads/paths throughout GB that intersect with raster pixels. However, I am unable to generate an output when using %Name% as the output table name as the file extension contains .tif.

I therefore used Parse path to remove the extension but I am struggling with how this should be used as a variable within the model. I am currently using the Name variable as a precondition and Zonal_%Value%_tbl for the output table name within Zonal stats, but this raises the following error:  ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters. Failed to execute (Zonal Statistics as Table).

How can I do this?

[image: Model Builder]

[image: Zonal stats parameters]

Comment: I think you need to use the actual name of the variable inside the percent signs.  You are using %Value% but there is nothing named 'Value' in your model. Try using %Name (2)% or renaming that box to 'Value'.

Comment: What a donut! I missed the (2) after Name. I tried using %Name (2)% and it worked. Thank you.